# css how to align a graphic on page

Tags: css

I'm trying to align a graphic which overlaps the main page element and pad elements.  How
to do this?  I have a blue circle button (click here) that I want placed in the following picture location on the page.

css:

[image]

Comment: Well since you provided no code at all and clearly haven't looked into this at all I will give a short yet amazing answer. **You move it**, could use `position: absolute;` with `top, bottom etc`, you could use good HTML and CSS and place it correctly in there, could use `margin` or `padding` the list goes on.

Comment: can't understand your problem, the code is important in almost css questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist but look into `position:relative`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place an element above all other elements at a specific position, you should move it out of all the other elements so it is a direct child of `<body>`. If you place it directly before the closing `</body>` tag, then it should be the topmost element if you're not using the z-index css-property anywhere. If you do so, apply it to your blue circle as well.

Then to place it to a specific location, use the following CSS:

```
#blue_circle {
position: absolute;
top: [whatever you want]px;
left: [whatever you want]px;
}
```

of course you can also use relative positioning (% instead of px) to set the position of your element.